# Does child logger inherit 'format' of root logger?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-logging

I understand that python logging allows to creates parent child relationship using: `logger = logging.getLogger(parent.child)`. Here the chain is: `Root logger <- parent <- child`

I have configured the root logger format using: `logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s:%(message)s')`

However, when I use the flask's `app.logger.info('some message')`, which I believe is the child of the root logger; it is not inheriting the format of the python root logger. Does child logger inherit format of root logger?

Comment: It should inherit the root's formatter. Could you show the actual code?